# Filtering before reducing properties

Tags: angular, typescript

trying to map Object to HttpParams but I want to exclude any parameter that is empty, null or undefined.

```
export function mapToHttpParams(obj: object): HttpParams {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
    .reduce((p, key) =>
        p.set(key, (typeof obj[key] === 'undefined' || obj[key] === null) ? '' : obj[key]),
      new HttpParams());
}
```

This code still includes those empty parameters and I want to do something like:

```
export function mapToHttpParams(obj: object): HttpParams {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
    .remove(obj[key] === null && obj[key] === '' && obj[key] === null)
    .reduce((p, key) =>
        p.set(key, (typeof obj[key] === 'undefined' || obj[key] === null) ? '' : obj[key]),
      new HttpParams());
}
```

Can't find proper way to do it - always getting compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for:

```
export function mapToHttpParams(obj: { [key: string]: string }): HttpParams {
    const params = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
        .filter(propName => !!obj[propName])
        .reduce((acc, cur) => { acc[cur] = obj[cur]; return acc; }, {} as { [key: string]: string });
    return new HttpParams({ fromObject: params });
}
```

Comment: unfortunately your code doesnn't compile - getting type{} is not assignable to HttpParams

Comment: You're right, I haven't tested it against the actual `HttpParams` interface. I updated the code, does it work now for you?

Comment: to be honest I need to have object ype as parameter - so export function mapToHttpParams(obj: object): HttpParams { is waht i need

Comment: It looks like that `HttpParamsOptions`, the argument to `HttpParams` needs an object whose values are string. How can you convert an arbitrary object to that?

Comment: If you really want `object: any` as the input parameter, you can use `(obj as any)[propName]` and `(obj as any)[cur]` to get rid of compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering them first, you could just pass the original object through the `reduce()` method

```
export function mapToHttpParams(obj: object): HttpParams {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
    .reduce((p, key) => obj[key] == null || obj[key] == '' ? p : p.set(key, obj[key]),
      new HttpParams());
}
```